# Store \pgfmathresult in a variable

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

The result of `\pgfmathparse` is automatically stored in `\pgfmathresult`. Is it possible to store it in an other variable, too?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use `\pgfmathsetmacro\mymacro{...}` instead of `\pgfmathparse{...}`.

From the v2.10 `pgfmanual`, section 62.1 *Commands for Parsing Expressions*, page 527:

> `\pgfmathsetmacro{<macro>}{<expression>}`
>   Defines `<macro>` as the value of `<expression>`. The result is a decimal without units.
>
> `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{<macro>}{<expression>}`
>   Defines `<macro>` as the value of `<expression>` LaTeX in points.
>
> `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{<macro>}{<expression>}`
>   Defines `<macro>` as the truncated value of `<expression>`.

In theory you could also say `\let\mymacro\pgfmathresult`, but I recommend the above macros.

Answer (score 6):

I guess with

```
\edef\myvar{\pgfmathresult}
```

when the value from `\pgfmathparse` has been computed. Or `\xdef` instead of `\edef` if you need it globally, i.e., outside the TiKZ environment in which the computation is performed.

Comment: Note that `\pgfmathresult` is already fully expand, so I would prefer `\let\myvar\pgfmathresult`, with `\global` as prefix if required.

Comment: @Martin: Is it possible to define one of the macros in your answer globally?

Comment: No. Adding `\global` in front of them shouldn't work.