# Divide integers and get a floating point number (for a pstricks coordinate)

Tags: diagrams, pstricks, pgfmath, dimensions

I'm making a picture with pstricks and would like to plot points whose coordinates are fractions a/c, b/c, where a, b, and c run over certain ranges. I tried using \numexpr but it rounds down. I wouldn't use \dimexpr, as I assume that a dimension (ending with pt or suchlike) isn't welcome as a pstricks coordinate. I tried using pgf but I can't get the syntax to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,multido}
\RequirePackage{pgf}%
\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=5cm,yunit=5cm}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(1,1)
\multido{\iC=1+1}{5}{%
  \multido{\iA=0+1}{\iC}{%
    \multido{\iB=0+1}{\iC}{%
      \pscircle*(\pgfmathparse{\iA/\iC},\pgfmathparse{\iB/\iC}){0.02}
    }
  }
}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Desired output (produced using TikZ, which works for this 5x5 example but runs out TeX's memory on the larger scales I want to use).
[image: Desired output]

Comment: I forget the pstricks syntax but can't you use postscript arithmetic here `\iA\space\iC\space div` ?

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,multido}
\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=5cm,yunit=5cm}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(1,1)
\multido{\iC=1+1}{5}{%
    \multido{\iA=0+1}{\iC}{%
        \multido{\iB=0+1}{\iC}{%
            \psdot(!\iA\space \iC\space div \iB\space \iC\space div)
        }%
    }%
}%
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,multido,pst-calculate}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=8}
\begin{pspicture}(2,2)
\multido{\iC=1+1}{20}{%
    \multido{\iA=0+1}{\numexpr\iC+1}{%
        \multido{\iB=0+1}{\numexpr\iC+1}{%
            \psdot[dotscale=0.5](\pscalculate{\iA/\iC},\pscalculate{\iB/\iC})
        }%
    }%
}%
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You forgot to invoke `\pgfmathresult`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,multido}
\RequirePackage{pgf}%
\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=5cm,yunit=5cm}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(1,1)
\multido{\iC=1+1}{5}{%
  \multido{\iA=0+1}{\iC}{%
    \multido{\iB=0+1}{\iC}{%
    \pgfmathparse{\iA/\iC}\xdef\myx{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathparse{\iB/\iC}\xdef\myy{\pgfmathresult}
    \pscircle*(\myx,\myy){0.02}
    }
  }
}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Just for curiosity, could you please also add your Ti*k*Z example? I am a bit surprised about the error you get.

**UPDATE**: I do not get any problems when doing this with Ti*k*Z, where the code is shorter, no packages are required and the compilation is more convenient (even though I really like PSTricks).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=10]
\foreach \iC in {1,...,15}{%
  \foreach \iA in {0,...,\iC}{%
   \foreach \iB in {0, ...,\iC}{%
      \draw[fill=black] ({\iA/\iC},{\iB/\iC}) circle (0.002);
    }
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: A 15x15 example]

Comment: May I ask why `\pgfmathparse{...}\pgfmathresult` cannot be put inside `\pscircle`, in particular as `\pscircle*(\pgfmathparse{\iA/\iC}\pgfmathresult,\pgfmathparse{\iB/\iC}\pgfmathresult){0.02}`, and you had to define `\myx` and `\myy`? I do not need `\myx` and `\myy` anywhere else.

Comment: @Hotschke Well, the parser may just not be OK with that.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. However, it is not obvious to me why. I was hoping to get an answer here why the parser is not OK with it.

Comment: @Hotschke I can only guess. It may just not be OK with two macros at a position in which it only expects a number or macro. I have switched almost completely to Ti*k*Z and forgot much of what I knew about pstricks, but most likely I never understood how the parser works there anyway. Note, however, that in Ti*k*Z `\draw[fill=black] (\pgfmathparse{\iA/\iC}\pgfmathresult,{\iB/\iC}) circle (0.002);` does not work for that reason. There, of course, you can do `\draw[fill=black] ({\iA/\iC},{\iB/\iC}) circle (0.002);` and the problem does not arise in the first place.

Comment: I agree that this is an XY problem. In pstricks one naturally uses postscript to do calculations and in tikz `\pgfmathparse` is run anyway. Both are more compact and do not need `\myx` and `\myy`.

Comment: Note also `\newcommand{\pgfmathparseandprint}[1]{\pgfmathparse{#1}\pgfmathresult}` cannot help here. I think [a comment by David Carlisle might explain it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93869/macros-and-pgfmath-within-put-in-picture-environment#comment200824_93876).

Answer (score 5):

Also available in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html), here wrapped up in `luamplib` so compile with `lualatex` or work out how to adapt it for [GMP](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/gmp?lang=en), or plain MP.

[image]

I've added a bit of color too.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85, luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    n = 25;
    for i = 1 upto n:
        for j = 0 upto i:
            for k = 0 upto i:
                fill fullcircle 
                     scaled 3 
                     shifted ((j/i, k/i) scaled (n*cm)) 
                     withcolor 3/4(j/i, k/i, i/n);
            endfor
        endfor
    endfor
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```